# Apache Bloodhound with gunicorn and nginx: prefix all urls

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, gunicorn

I recently installed Apache Bloodhound on my server, which uses gunicorn and reverse proxy with nginx.  That same server is also serving up my django site with uwsgi and a proxy from '/'.  I want to proxy to gunicorn with a '/bloodhound' to port 8001, which works (I can see the landing page for bloodhound).

The problem arises when I try to hit any other page.  Bloodhound thinks it's running on '/', so if I click on the login link it redirects to '/login' instead of '/bloodhound/login', understandably.  Is there any way to set up either bloodhound or gunicorn to run on '/bloodhound'?  I know how to do it in django, but I'm new to bloodhound/gunicorn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to find out what framework bloodhound ran on (and I'm not sure I ever did), I ended up at this page: http://osdir.com/ml/web.wiki.moin.general/2005-02/msg00138.html

It had some python in it that seemed to reference a 'SCRIPT_NAME' variable, so I added the following to my gunicorn init script: `--env SCRIPT_NAME=/bloodhound`

And it magically worked!